# C# List<string> in linux with Mono

Tags: c#, linux

I have an executable file that processes a large number (1000+) of strings and adds each one to a List of strings. It is coded in C#, compiled in Visual Studio 2017 on a windows machine, then exported to and run on a Linux machine with Mono. Oddly enough, writing all of the strings to a text file works just fine, but adding them to the list causes the program's user interface to freeze and become unresponsive.

Here's my code:

```
        client.BigDB.LoadRange("Clans", "ByName", null, startAt + "0000000000", stopAt + "zzzzzzzzzz", 1000, delegate (DatabaseObject[] o)
        {
            foreach (DatabaseObject obj in o)
            {
                //this section here does not work as intended
                //string ClanName = obj.GetString("name");
                //ClanNames.Add(ClanName);
                //main.ui.AppendTestBox(ClanName);
                //Clans++;

                //but this section works perfectly
                using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("ClanNameList.txt"))
                {
                    w.Write(obj.GetString("name") + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }                
        });
```

After inspecting the output file, I suspect that it is getting caught on the following string: "AK Union, Local 47". It processed every previous kind of character without problems, but it appears to not like commas for some reason. How do I get around this, if that's actually what's going on?

I did try to search for this problem on google and this site, but the search results are wildly unhelpful and quite unrelated to what I need :(

Comment: Is this threaded by any chance?

Comment: i'm a bigger newbie than i thought i was, I'm not sure what you mean. What do you mean by "this"?

Comment: I googled "threaded code", and I don't believe that this code is threaded. It extracts the keyed string "name", then adds it to a list, then adds it to a textbox (for debugging purposes).

Answer (score 0):

I cant see exactly your problem, though one thing i would suggest is update once via a `StringBuilder`, not 1000 times

```
    client.BigDB.LoadRange("Clans", "ByName", null, startAt + "0000000000", stopAt + "zzzzzzzzzz", 1000, delegate (DatabaseObject[] o)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DatabaseObject obj in o)
        {
            var name = obj.GetString("name");
            ClanNames.Add(name);
            sb.Append(name);
        }      
        main.ui.AppendTestBox(sb.ToString());

    });
```

[StringBuilder.Append Method (System.Text)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.append(v=vs.110).aspx)